# Configurar Qt Creator para compilación estática

Tags: c++, qt

He seguido los pasos de [este enlace](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-building.html) para descargar y compilar las librerías de Qt de forma estática, como paso previo para poder usarlas en una compilación. 
Pero ahora no sé cómo configurar QtCreator para poder enlazarlas. Entiendo que el proceso es crear un nuevo kit en el menu `Build and Run->Kits ->Add Kit`, pero una vez allí no sé cómo configurar dicho kit.
Estoy usando `QtCreator 3.5.1`, basado en `Qt 5.5.1` usando `gcc 5.2.1`, bajo linux.
Las librerías estáticas están en `/ruta/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/lib/`

Comment: Cuando crees tu proyecto selecciona ese kit

Comment: Disculpa, ahora releo el mensaje y veo que está mal expresado. Me refiero a cómo he de configurar ese kit para que pueda realizar una compilación estática. Ahora edito un poco el mensaje

Comment: Para compilar de forma estatica solo coloca `CONFIG += static` en tu .pro

Comment: Fue lo primero que intenté, por aquello de ir a lo fácil, pero no funcionó. Además entiendo que he de enlazar a las librerías estáticas, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Estas seguro que lo has compilado a Qt de forma estatica

Comment: Si has compilado Qt de forma estatica, y estas usando ese kit entonces automaticamente se enlazaran a las librerias estaticas con lo anterior.

Comment: A ver, la duda es cómo configurar el kit para que me enlace a las librerías estáticas, no usarlo :-)

Comment: Si al momento de compilar Qt le has indicado que genere los estaticos (en el caso de linux los .a), solo bastara que uses ese kit más el comando `CONFIG += static` en tu .pro, si no tienes los .a, Qt los compilara de forma dinamica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estos son los pasos que he hecho finalmente y que me han resultado.

1.- Añadir -como dice la documentación- las nuevas librerías al path

2.- Crear->`Menu Tools->Options->Build and Run` un nuevo kit seleccionando en el cuadro de Qt version el apropiado (ya debe de salir disponible).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.- En el nuevo kit ,en `Build Environment` añadir las librerías estáticas:
**LD_LIBRARY_PATH  /miruta/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qtbase/lib/**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4.- Por último, en la aplicación, añadir `CONFIG += static` en el fichero *.pro