# Qt. Se pierde el estilo al enlazar de forma estática

Tags: c++, qt

Cuando compilo una aplicación enlazando de forma estática, pierdo el estilo de la misma. Al ejecutar el binario me sale este aviso:

`QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.`

Estoy compilando desde `QtCreator 3.5.1` con `GCC 5.2.1 20151129, 64 bit` bajo linux.

Vista de la aplicación en la versión *estática* (sin estilo):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vista de la aplicación en la versión *dinámica* (con estilo):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualizo:

Siguiendo la pista al mensaje de error he visto este mismo problema [aquí](https://forum.qt.io/topic/75398/qt-5-8-0-qapplication-invalid-style-override-passed-ignoring-it):

Al OP se le recomienda que haga ejecute lo siguiente para ver qué pasa con los plugins.

```
qDebug() << QStyleFactory::keys();
qDebug() << QApplication::style()->metaObject()->className();
```

Hago igual y esta es mi salida:

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() ignoring "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3" since plugins are disabled in static builds
loaded library "Xcursor"
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() ignoring "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.Xcb.QXcbGlIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.5" since plugins are disabled in static builds
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() ignoring "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformThemeFactoryInterface.5.1" since plugins are disabled in static builds
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() ignoring "org.qt-project.Qt.QPlatformInputContextFactoryInterface.5.1" since plugins are disabled in static builds
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() ignoring "org.qt-project.Qt.QStyleFactoryInterface" since plugins are disabled in static builds    
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() ignoring "org.qt-project.Qt.QIconEngineFactoryInterface" since plugins are disabled in static builds
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() ignoring "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface" since plugins are disabled in static builds
loaded library "libdbus-1"
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() ignoring "org.qt-project.Qt.QAccessibleFactoryInterface" since plugins are disabled in static builds
```

Ahora me queda saber cómo cargar esos plugins en el enlazado.

Comment: Todas las compilaciones son estáticas ¿a qué te refieres?

Comment: Seguramente no haya sido muy riguroso al plantear la pregunta. Pido disculpas. Quiero decir que compilo contra las versiones estáticas de las librerias (las .a). Vengo de aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125128/configurar-qt-creator-para-compilaci%c3%b3n-est%c3%a1tica

Comment: También necesitaríamos conocer a qué te refieres con "*se pierde el estilo de la aplicación*".

Comment: Pues se pierden los colores y se distorsionan tamaños y proporciones. He editado el post para poner imágenes en ambos casos.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que compilas de forma estática? La aplicación desde luego no puede ser porque una compilación estática no genera binario ejecutable...

Comment: Pues me refiero a la aplicación. ¿Puede ser que el término correcto sea "Construcción estática"? Si es así edito el título para evitar confusiones. Me refiero a esto: http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtee-static-linking.html

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo es *enlazar* de forma estática las librerías de Qt... al montar un ejecutable puedes enlazar con diferentes librerías de forma dinámica y/o estática... pero el ejecutable no se crea de forma estática.

Comment: Los cambios de estilos ¿suceden si compilas para otras plataformas?

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que en el montaje estático te falta enlazar alguna dependencia... en el dinámico no falla porque las librerías dinámicas son binarios completos

Comment: @eferion, gracias por el apunte. Ahora corrijo el post

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, no he tenido ocasión de compilar para otra plataforma. Ahora me tengo que pelear con la compilación cruzada

Comment: @eferion, cuando compilé las librerías me dio un error en qtwayland, y opté por eliminarla de la lista. Ahora que lo dices, ese puede ser el error. De hecho casi lo había olvidado

Comment: Pues mira a ver si es eso y si no seguimos investigando...

Comment: @eferion Bueno, he vuelto a compilar los fuentes de qt y esta vez sin errores y el problema persiste.

Comment: @user3733164 las dependencias de las que hablo son a nivel de la aplicación, no al compilar qt... tiene pinta que lo que sucede es que en el montaje estático estás obviando la librería que contiene los estilos y por eso no los encuentra al arrancar la aplicación